# My jmeter Script is executing successfully even after the server is down. It is not throwing any errors and giving the response code as 200

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

i am doing a load test on one of our website.

My jmeter Script is executing successfully even after the server is down. It is not throwing any errors and also giving the response code as 200.

I have tried all other solutions like Response assertions but that is not helping me.

Can you guys help me with this? I am not sure of what i am missing here.

[Server status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU4sD.png)

[jmeter response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu4WP.png)

Comment: I have added the links to images in my query post. Kindly refer to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes below 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) as successful, it doesn't do any extra checks of content so if your server responds with an [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) error but having non-error HTTP Status code - JMeter will consider it as OK.

Ideally in case of error your server should respond with [HTTP Status Code 5xx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) so I would recommend raising an issue to correct the behaviour.

In the meantime consider adding a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to explicitly check whether the response contains what it is supposed to be containing (or alternatively that it does not contain `error` word)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your response. Just to check if this is a server side issue, I am hosting the same website in different server and planning to test it. Regarding the Response Assertion, i have checked if the response is containing any error word as you suggested, but it is a negative. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What is the response you get when you hit API from POSTMAN tool?
If you are getting `200` then please consult your developer to handle error code properly.

If you are getting `400` or `500`, then there is something missing from your `Response Assertion`.